# When I try to update a user profile via my app on localhost:3000, the change does not occur in MongoDB, user-account/users collection is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

index.html

```
<script>

    function editProfile() {
        document.querySelector('.container').style.display = 'none'
        document.querySelector('.container-edit').style.display = 'block'

        const  name = document.querySelector('#name').textContent
        document.querySelector('#input-name').value = name

        const  email = document.querySelector('#email').textContent
        document.querySelector('#input-email').value = email

        const  interests = document.querySelector('#interests').textContent
        document.querySelector('#input-interests').value = interests
    }

    function saveProfile() {
        document.querySelector('#name').textContent = document.querySelector('#input-name').value
        document.querySelector('#email').textContent = document.querySelector('#input-email').value
        document.querySelector('#interests').textContent = document.querySelector('#input-interests').value

        document.querySelector('.container').style.display = 'block'
        document.querySelector('.container-edit').style.display = 'none'
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <h1 id='header'>User Profile</h1>
        <img src='profile-picture' alt="Profile Picture">
        Name: <h3 id='name'>Andrea Hill</h3>
        <hr />
        Email: <h3 id='email'>andrea.hill@gmal.com</h3>
        <hr />
        Interests: <h3 id='interests'>coding</h3>
        <hr />
        <button class='button' onclick="editProfile()">Edit Profile</button>
    </div>

    <div class='container-edit'>
        <h1 id='edit-header'>User Profile</h1>
        <img src='profile-picture' alt="Profile Picture">
        <label for="input-name">Name:</label>
        Name: <input id='input-name' type='text' />
        <hr />
        <label for="input-email">Name:</label>
        Email: <input id='input-email' type='email' />
        <hr />
        <label for="input-interests">Name:</label>
        Interests: <input id='input-interests' type='text' />
        <button class='button' onclick="saveProfile()">Save Profile</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.get('/get-profile', function (req, res) {
    var response = res;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var db = client.db('user-account');
        var query = { userid: 1 };
        db.collection('users').findOne(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            client.close();
            response.send(result);
        });
    });
});

app.post('/update-profile', function (req, res) {
    console.log('update-profile route triggered');
    var userObj = req.body;
    var response = res;

    console.log('connecting to the db...');

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var db = client.db('user-account');
        userObj['userid'] = 1
        var query = { userid: 1 };
        var newValues = { $set: userObj };

        console.log('successfully connected to the user-account db');
        console.log('userObj:', userObj);

        db.collection('users').updateOne(query, newValues, {upsert: true}, function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('successfully updated or inserted');
            client.close();
            response.send(userObj);
        });
    });
});

app.get('/profile-picture', function(req, res) {
    var img = fs.readFileSync('images/profile-1.jpeg');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

tried with

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"name": "John", "email": "john@example.com", "interests": "programming"}" http://localhost:3000/update-profile

same problem

mongo is running on a docker container, in the logs I can see only GET requests, no POST requests.
The app is running fine, and I don't see any error messages in the console or in the docker logs

I can update the users collection only directly via mongo-express or mongo-compass, but not from my app.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 :
The below code shows that, you are trying to Update the data, but you are using the "app.post", it should be "app.put".

```
db.collection('users').updateOne(query, newValues, {upsert: true}, function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('successfully updated or inserted');
            client.close();
            response.send(userObj);
        });
```

Post is to insert the data and not update. So make sure what you want to do.

Point 2):

Open developer tools and go to Network tab and see the request that is being sent. [image: Network Tab]. In the Payload you can see your data being sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ajay, I changed it to app.put, but no effect. In browser I don't even see a payload tab, unless I create a document manually via mongo-express interface on port 8081. But if I make a change via app on port 3000 and click save, it just nothing happens, I don't see any new entries in network tab.

Comment: It only means that, you are not sending anything in the body. When you try to insert or update data, there should be data sent in the body. What front end technology are you trying to send the data with?

Comment: Yes exactly, nothing is being sent to the body. I am fairly new in this area and may be I am missing something important. I am using intelij IDE and working with 2 files - index.html and server.js. So from my understanding I am using html + JS on frontend and Node.js in backend. I am using 2 docker containers - one on port 27017(MongoDB) and one on 8081(mongo-express). The app and the MongoDB are accessible on their respective ports, and DB can be modified without any issues via mongo-express interface or Mongo-Compass. But apparently can not be modified via my application (port 3000).

Comment: Hello sir, I got you. 
In layman’s terms, whatever the data the user feeds on the html page, the backend( Node js) in your case should receive it. Only then you will be able to process it. I would request you to first go through Node js tutorial on how to send the data in different ways.  Later you can see how to send it from html. Which is usually done with Jquery, Javascript, Angular or any front end frameworks.

Comment: Yep, but it is not working. I recreated containers couple of times, nothing helps. I already troubleshooting this 2 days and I have no more ideas

Comment: What do you mean how to send data in different ways? You see my js code, is it not enough to send the data? I took the code from a tutorial and it should work . So you think that the issue is with code?

Comment: On button click you have saveProfile() method. But this saveProfile() method should call Node Js, app.post right? Where is that connection sir? Or have you pasted incomplete code ?

Comment: Yes Ajay, I think you are right. That is the whole code indeed, this is what I see in the video tutorial.  But I think it is missing something in saveProfile method. Because when I click "Save Profile" in browser, I have the feeling it is just dummy button, it is not capable to trigger any operation. It is just saving from browser prospective, no matter if I edit the current profile of Andrea Hill, or create a new one. So I also think that is missing something, despite of the fact that in video tutorial it seems to work with this code. According ChatGPT this is a valid code as well..

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did some changes in function SaveProfile() in index.html and now I see my POST request in Network Tab. Currently It hangs in pending state for some reason, and I still don't have an update profile in MongoDB, but at least there is a progress from request prospective.